# How many styles to do?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have a task to make different styles for each screen of android devices. For ex: values-small-nodpi, values-small-ldpi, values-small-mdpi ... values-normall-nodpi, values-normall-ldpi ... Summary 28 different styles. is it correctly to do so many styles or it's enough to do only values-small, values-normal ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

For example, for strings, you could just have one version. This is I guess, quite obvious.

For font sizes, you could use only a few buckets. Say, small, normal, large and xlarge.

For dimensions, i.e, which you would perhaps use for view's sizes, or say margins or paddings, you could again use only a few buckets (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi etc)

I don't see a reason why you would have to create 28 copies of each resource. Handling only a few buckets would ensure that you will be targeting almost all the devices.

As @Davhed mentioned, by doing so, you would be unnecessarily increasing your apk size.

Comment: Primarily it's  the size of the widgets

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to do styles as you need.
It is not necessary (and almost impossible) to have all possibile styles.

Answer (score 0):

Google has very comprehensive documentation on this topic. See this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It depends on your needs,but if you target the minimum resolution for each DPI variant than you should be OK. If you have 28 versions of each graphic your app will end up being an extremely large file size.

Comment: To follow up, there is a handy table of market share per screen configuration at http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens